# How to solve net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID smtp.js

Tags: smtp

I set up everything properly according to https://www.smtpjs.com/ and it should work fine but I  ran into this error in the browser [image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by **Fixing the date and time** on my computer since I was running on localHost.